# Russian Roulette Game

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A single bullet is randomly put into a 6-chamber revolver. 2 players (A and B) take turns pulling the trigger with the barrel pointed at themself. Each time the trigger is pulled, the barrel rotates to the next chamber (I think this is how revolvers work?). What is the probability of surviving if you're player A or B?

So my intuition tells me that each player has equal probability of surviving. Player $A$ will be assigned to chambers 1,3,5, and player $B$ will be assigned to chambers 2,4,6. The bullet is equally likely to be in any of these chambers, so each player has a 1/2 chance, I think.

I wanted to prove this with actual equations using conditional probability for practice, but it seems that I am doing something wrong in my work below.

There are 3 rounds, where a round is defined by players $A$ and $B$ pulling the trigger in sequence. Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3$ denote the events that players A and B survive rounds 1,2,3.

## First round

$$
P(A_1) = \frac{5}{6} \\
P(A_1^c) = \frac{1}{6} \\
P(B_1) = P(B_1|A_1)P(A_1) + P(B_1|A_1^c)P(A_1^c) \\
= \frac{4}{5}\frac{5}{6} + 1*\frac{1}{6} \\
= \frac{5}{6} = P(A_1)
$$
So players $A$ and $B$ have equal probability of surviving the first round.

## Second round

$$
P(A_2) = P(A_2|A_1, B_1)P(A_1, B_1) + P(A_2|A_1, B_1^c)P(A_1, B_1^c) + \text{zero terms} \\
= \frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{2}{3} \\
\\
P(B_2) = P(B_2|A_1, B_1, A_2)P(A_1,B_1,A_2) + P(B_2|A_1, B_1, A_2^c)P(A_1,B_1,A_2^c) + \text{zero terms} \\
= \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2} + 1*\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Hmmm, the 2 players don't have equal probability of surviving the 2nd round.

## Third round

$$
P(A_3) = P(A_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2) + 
P(A_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2^c)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2^c) + \text{zero terms} \\
= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} + 1*\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3} \\
\\
P(B_3) = P(B_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3) + 
P(B_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c)  + \text{zero terms}\\
=P(B_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c) \\
= \frac{1}{6}
$$

So it seems that something is wrong with my calculations in rounds 2 and 3 because the 2 probabilities aren't equal? In addition, how do I go about computing the probability that $A$ or $B$ survives all 3 rounds, i.e., $P(A_1, A_2, A_3)$ and $P(B_1, B_2, B_3)$. I understand 1 is the complement of the other, but I'm unsure how to get either one. It seems to calculate $P(A_1, A_2, A_3)$, I would have to do something like:

$$
P(A_1,A_2,A_3) + P(B_1,B_2,B_3) = 1 \\
P(A_1, A_2, A_3) = P(A_1, A_2, A_3|B_1^c)P(B_1^c) + P(A_1, A_2, A_3|B_2^c)P(B_2^c) + P(A_1, A_2, A_3|B_3^c)P(B_3^c) = P(B_1^c) + P(B_2^c) + P(B_3^c) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5}{6} > 1 \\
P(B_1, B_2, B_3) = P(B_1, B_2, B_3|A_1^c)P(A_1^c) + P(B_1, B_2, B_3|A_2^c)P(A_2^c) + P(B_1, B_2, B_3|A_3^c)P(A_3^c) = P(A_1^c) + P(A_2^c) + P(A_3^c) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} > 1 \\
$$
But this is obviously wrong. Is this the correct way to get $P(A_1, A_2, A_3)$ and $P(A_1, A_2, A_3)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second round, you must also include the term
$$
P(B_2|A_1^c, B_1, A_2^c)P(A_1^c,B_1,A_2^c) = 1\cdot P(A_1^c) = \frac16,
$$
which is not zero.
When this term is included, $P(B_2) = P(A_2) = \frac23.$

In the third round, your calculation of $P(A_3)$ should include the term
$$ P(A_3|A_1,B_1^c,A_2,B_2^c)P(A_1,B_1^c,A_2,B_2^c) =\frac16$$

while your calculation of $P(B_3)$ should include the terms
$$ P(B_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c) =\frac16$$
and
$$ P(B_3|A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c)P(A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2,A_3^c) =\frac16.$$

When you include these missing terms, $P(A_3) = P(B_3) = \frac12,$
which is the correct probability that each player survives at the end.

---

Actually the probabilities "in real life" should be $P(A_3) = \frac13,$
$P(B_3) = \frac23,$ because if the first five chambers are empty then when $A$ hands the revolver to $B$ to try the final chamber, $B$ shoots $A$.
Avid readers of *MAD Magazine* [would know this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWEtr.jpg).
A variation on this theme was a plot element of *The Deer Hunter*.

Comment: I like how the people to the left are smiling at first but rapidly grow worried as their conditional probabilities of getting the bullet increase :-)

Comment: Hmm, so I didn't include those terms because I thought events $A_1^c$ and $A_2^c$ are mutually exclusive, like player $A$ can't die in round 1 AND round 2? So isn't the probability of $P(A_1^c, A_2^c) = 0$ ?

Comment: You defined $A_2$ as the probability that player $A$ survives round $2.$ I interpreted this as, "Player $A$ is still alive at the end of round $2$." If $A$ dies in round $1$ then $A$ is not alive at the end of round $2$, hence $P(A_1^c,A_2^c) = P(A_1^c).$ If you have a different definition of $A_2$ then you will have to rework a lot more of your probabilities, not just the terms I pointed out.

Comment: One conceptual difficulty with your definitions is how you define "surviving round $2$" or "not surviving round $2$" if someone is killed in round $1,$ because then round $2$ doesn't actually happen. I resolved this by assuming that once someone dies, all the remaining rounds occur immediately with no change in anyone's life status. An alternative is that you have three possible outcomes for $A$ in round $2$: $A$ pulls the trigger but survives, $A$ pulls the trigger and dies, or round $2$ never occurs. In that case you have to account for the the "never occurs" terms to your calculations.

Comment: Note that by simple set arithmetic on the events, $A_1^c\cap A_2$ and $A_1^c\cap A_2^c$ are a partition of $A_1^c,$ so $P(A_1^c) = P(A_1^c,A_2) + P(A_1^c,A_2^c).$ So if you say $P(A_1^c,A_2^c)=0$ then you are saying that $P(A_1^c,A_2)=P(A_1^c)=\frac16,$ that is, this is the probability that $A$ dies in round $1$ but survives round $2.$

Comment: Regarding your first comment: yes, you're right. I think I'm confusing myself with my own definitions of what these events mean. I think ideally I would have liked my definitions to adhere to if someone dies in a round then the rest of the rounds doesn't happen, but that is clearly not what I did in my work because I assumed that if A dies in a round, then player $B$ will still have a turn. So now I see why $P(A_1^c, A_2^c) \neq 0$. With my definition this is basically saying "what is the probability that $A$ dies in round 1, and stays dead in round 2, and that's just $P(A_1)$ as you said.

Comment: I think I'll try defining the events using your alternative approach as well for practice.

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem again, and now I'm kind of confused why I originally said $P(B_1|A_1) = \frac{4}{5}$. Doesn't this assume the second player randomly spins the barrel again after player 1 pulls the trigger and survives? Is the probability that the bullet is in the next consecutive chamber actually $\frac{1}{5}$? If so, then I am confused because originally each chamber has a $\frac{1}{6}$ probability of having the bullet.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about spinning the cylinder each time the revolver passes to the next player, but does say the cylinder advances to the next chamber each time the trigger is pulled, which would be irrelevant if we spun the cylinder each time, so I assumed we spin only before the first round.

Comment: If we do **not** spin the cylinder each time, but only once at the start, you get $P(B_1\mid A_1) = \frac45$ because **now we know** that the chamber the first player dropped the hammer on is empty, and the cartridge is in **one of the other five** chambers. But if you **do** spin the cylinder between the first player's first turn and the second player's first turn, $P(B_1\mid A_1)=\frac56,$ because the cartridge could equally likely be in any of the six chambers, including the one the second player is about to drop the hammer on. This increases the second player's chance of survival.